# Student “B” will have read (the equivalent of) only 12 school days

Tags: grammar

I saw one sentence.

> By the end of 6th grade, student “A” will have read the equivalent of 60 whole school days.
>
> Student “B” will have read only 12 school days.

So the last sentence has something omitted and repetitive.

I mean, Student “B” will have read (**the equivalent of**) only 12 school days.

Comment: I have no idea what it means to say someone has ***read*** some number of days, and I've got even less idea why someone else might "read" ***the equivalent of*** some number of days. But consider an example that makes sense: *John has worked the equivalent of 10 whole days. But Jane has only worked 4 days.* In a context like that, it's quite possible Jane *also* did her work in units of less than a complete day (perhaps she worked 8 ***half-days***). It's not syntactically or logically *necessary* to keep repeating ***the equivalent of*** in such contexts - it can be ***assumed / implied***.

Comment: Actually I saw a poster; https://www.pinterest.it/pin/82401868168975254/ and https://www.pinterest.co.kr/pin/495888608948136209/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your analysis.  There is no particular rule here, but the first sentence establishes that we are using "equivalent school days" as a measure of time, (rather than an actual count of days) so it can be reasonably assumed that the same convention is in place for student B

The tense and the use of a direct object feels a little off

> The student will have been reading for the equivalent of 12 school days.

Presumably, if one school day is about 5 hours, then this means that student A has spent 300 hours reading but B has spent 60 hours reading.  Perhaps student B has spent longer doing painting or arithmetic?

Comment: Actually I saw a poster; https://www.pinterest.co.kr/pin/495888608948136209/